# ActiveX control: "Automation server can't create object"

Tags: html, activex

I'm trying to use an ActiveX control:

```
shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
```

But it is giving me an error:

> Message: Automation server can't create object

What's going wrong?

Comment: which browser you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveX - Automation Server Can't Create Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157183/activex-automation-server-cant-create-object)

Comment: @4M01 — Internet Explorer. Anything else would error and complain that ActiveXObject was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Internet Explorer Security Settings. Follow the seteps

1. Go to Tools (or press Alt+X)
2. Go to Internet Options
3. Click on "Security" Tab. If you are loading your web site from internet, select "Internet" Icon, if you are loading your site form local computer select "Local Intranet"
4. Click "Custom Level" Button
5. find "Initialize and Script Activex controls not marked as safe for scripting" and select "Prompt" radio button and click ok.

thats all. cheerrs!!