# How to call activex

Tags: php, activex

how can we call active x control, so that browser will ask to install active x with yellow color bar on top.

I have tried to call DLL with Active x

but it is giving error:

```
Message: Automation server can't create object
```

Comment: What code are you using to call the DLL?

Comment: Searching for your error message finds [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157183/activex-automation-server-cant-create-object), doesn't that answer the question?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is 'ActiveX' not the term IE uses for flash and certain javascripts?

Comment: @poepje — No, it really isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is browser specific issue. In IE go to `Tools > Internet Options > Security`, click on Custom Level. In security settings window, under "`Activex controls and Plug-ins` > `Initialize and script Activex Control not marked as safe for scripting`" set to `Prompt`