# IE9, Automation server can't create object error while using CertEnroll.dll

Tags: automation, internet-explorer-9, x509certificate, activexobject

In my web page, a `JS` block like this:

```
var classFactory = new ActiveXObject("X509Enrollment.CX509EnrollmentWebClassFactory");

// Other initialize CertEnroll Objects
```

It works fine in `windows7(32bit or 64bit)` with `IE8(32bit)`, as long as I change the IE8 secure setting, enable Initializing and Script ActiveX controls not marked as safe.

But when use IE9(32bit), I try anything I can find on web, it reports error "Automation server can't create object."

I even created a static html file, save it in my hard disk, and then open it with IE9(32bit), it worked fine. Then I put the html file on my web site, visit the html file with url, then it came up with the error message again.

I have worked on this problem for 4 days, any suggestion would be appreciated.

3Q. I hope you can read my words as I'm not an native English speaker.

Comment: I reset the IE9 settings and then tried secure setting again, then it works. So, something in the IE9 settings prevented the certenroll activex object from running. I should have back up the regedit status to compare the difference. I hope this issue can help you.

Comment: Is you website added to the trusted zone?

Comment: There is a bug in IE10 and IE11 (probably IE9 too), that if you have set a custom security level, then use the "Reset all zones to default level" button, and then view the settings via "Custom level...", the radio buttons will not accurately reflect the reset settings. Make sure to hit OK to close out of Internet Options after using "Reset all zones", then check the settings via "Custom level...", and the radio buttons will reflect the true settings.

Comment: hello sir can you share your code i need it

Answer (score 37):

a) Go to Tools-->Internet Options

b) Select security tab

c) Click on Trusted Sites (or Local Intranet depending on whether your site is trusted or not)

d) Click on Custom Level

e) Ensure that "Initialize and script active x controls is not marked safe for scripting"  is enabled - this comes under Activex controls and plug-ins section towards 1/4th of the scroll bar.

Click OK, OK.

Once this is completed, clear the browser cookies and cache. Close all your browser sessions. Reopen the IE to launch your site.

Try to disable the setting in step (e) to see if the problem comes back - that should give more insight to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As described in my question, step (e) has been done before, which helped nothing. It only happened on one PC. After I reset IE settings, it never comes up again.

Comment: «Initialize and script active x controls is not marked safe for scripting» was the cause for me.

Comment: this also solved my problem. if for any reason the choice is grayed out, try to change regkey directly, https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/microsoft_ie_version_7/2014-07-03/finding/V-6245

Comment: worked for me as well !! thanks . is it Possible to perform same task in chrome or firefox or even edge instead of IE ?