# Symfony2 filesize constraint in form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to add filesize constraint to my form in order to prohibit users to upload files larger than 2M (as set in my php.ini) and I tried the following:
In the formBuilder:

```
->add('avatar', 'file', array( 
            'label'  => 'Insert foto',
            'required' => false,
            'constraints'=> array(
                new File(array('maxSize'=>'2048k',
                'maxSizeMessage'=>'More than 2MB!!'))),
            'label_attr'   =>  array(
                'class' => 'control-label'
            ),
            'attr'   =>  array(
                'class'           => 'form-control filestyle',
                'placeholder'     => 'Foto'... etc,
```

Also I added file property to my main entity class

```
    /**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "2048k",
 *     mimeTypes = {"image/png"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid PNG file",
 *     maxSizeMessage = "Upload not more than 2M size files"
 * )
 */
protected $avatar;
```

In my controller I get the file with this:

```
$file = $form['avatar']->getData();
```

but still all the manipulations are done only AFTER the file is actually uploaded to my server. I dont want to upload it if it is larger than 2MB, instead I want to display an error message. Maybe I should use Formevents but no working example was found. Any ideas would be helpful. Thank You.

Comment: Javascript or alike approach will work, but not a bullet-proof solution since javascript could be easily disabled or altered. Better to validate server-side, if you still want on javascript check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212041/it-is-possible-to-validate-the-size-and-type-of-input-file-in-html5

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check filesizes before the file is uploaded, then you'll need to take a [JavaScript approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491455/check-filesize-before-uploading-to-file-system).

PHP (and Symfony) are server side and can only deal with uploaded files after they have been uploaded. JavaScript is client side and can check files before they are uploaded.

I would put up with it being uploaded and check it as you are at the moment; it's the most reliable approach.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep your advice, but now I would find out if there is a more like 'Symfony way' to do that. In addition, as far as I understand JS client validation is not favoured, e.g. in order to be on the safe side we need to make all valdations on server side. Or maybe I am mistakened..

Comment: Best to let Symfony do that; as you are doing with `maxSize` and `->add('avatar', 'file')` in your formType. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951294/symfony2-file-upload-step-by-step) should help you.