# How to enable clients run exe file from website ? - ActiveXObject bad idea

Tags: javascript, exe, remote-access, activexobject

I built a website, where there is a few **links for exe files**, i want users can run it from their machines.

Now, the way i made it, is by using JS with ActiveXObject.

```
var sw = new ActiveXObject('WScript.shell');
sw.exec(file);
```

Then - it's gave the error: "automation server can't create object". **I solve it**, as described here:

[IE9, Automation server can't create object error while using CertEnroll.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686040/ie9-automation-server-cant-create-object-error-while-using-certenroll-dll)

(see the 1st answer)

But, the solution was good only for me (I mean for the local computer, where i made changes in the internet securitu options).

It's not a solution for the end users, because what i want is to publish this site to a lot of people, and i already understood that it's absolutley un safe to enable the ActiveXObject opening (as described in the link above).

[Even if that was safe - i don't excpect all the users to change their settings, reset cookies etc.]

**Someone has idea instead how to enable them open my links ? ...**

Thanks !!

Comment: Browsers are basically moving away from facilities to run arbitrary native code from the web. Security implications are clear, even if you've never tried to download a movie from a dubious site. Is it a general audience site rather than an corporate environment?

Comment: It's an organizational site, with education stuff. The files (links) must be with exe extension. and i want give the users way for accessing it..

Comment: But it isn't e.g. a University where students can be forced to connect from CS labs with a given pre-configured browser, right? As I said, there're strong ongoing efforts on the opposite direction. You could write a "Run arbitrary programs from web sites without user intervention" plug-in users could install but, who would install such a thing?

Comment: I really don't know. quite new in this. What you suggest?